# PowerCLI has an hidden vc alias, I can't figure where it comes from and whether there's more of its like

Tags: powershell, alias, undocumented-behavior

A few years ago, I accidently stumbled upon an "hidden" PowerShell alias in VMware PowerCLI, `vc`, which can be used instead of `Connect-ViServer`.
This `vc` command is invisible to both `Get-Command` and `Get-Alias`, it's not recognized by command completion (not that you really need it to), and I could only relate it to `Connect-ViServer` by its output and behavior.

I found this specific pseudo-alias to be pretty useful in my PowerCLI work, and I always wondered how this worked, and whether there were other such hidden shortcuts.
Today, I searched my system for 2-letter and 3-letter commands unknown to Get-Command, and the only ones that came out beside `vc` were shortened Get-* commands (as explained by @vrdse below).

1. Can anyone explain where/how this `vc` pseudo-alias is defined ?
2. How can I find similar hidden commands more efficiently than with the below script or by sheer luck ?

Here's my (quick and dirty) script for 3-letter aliases, which ran for about an hour (!) on my system, and found nothing but shortened Get-* commands :
(Caution: blindly running random commands as I did is NOT recommended)

```
$az = [char[]]('a'[0]..'z'[0])
foreach ($i in $az) {
    write $i
    foreach ($j in $az) {
        write $i$j
        foreach ($k in $az) {
            if (!(gcm -ea ig $i$j$k)) {
                try {iex $i$j$k; write-warning $i$j$k} catch {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: take a look at `Get-Help *alias*` ... [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I should have stated that these hidden aliases do not show up in Get-Aliases either, if that's what you mean. Question updated.

Comment: ah! that makes more sense. [*grin*] what you are seeing MAY be from using the `[Alias()]` advanced function attribute.

Comment: For the Get-* functions that you mentioned: You can run all Get-* functions without the `Get-`. Meaning, these are not aliases.

Comment: @vrdse Good point! Never heard of this behavior before... I feel silly for missing this, and will correct my question again. Only `vc` is left then.

Comment: What is `write`?

Comment: @js2010 `get-command write` It's Write-Output.

Comment: @SagePourpre oh, unix doesn't have it as an alias

Comment: Yeah, honestly, using aliases is not the best recommended practice. One of the reason is exactly that. Aliases makes your script less portable and more subject to breakage. Some aliases, just like you proved, doesn't exists on all systems. Powershell 7 got rid of a lot of the aliases, so this will make script harder to migrate. I personally avoid aliases most of the time except (Foreach / Select /Where).

Comment: @SagePourpre That's why I said "quick and dirty script". Aliases bring you a quicker and more compact command line, which is critically useful with PowerShell's very descriptive cmdlets (which on the other hand make scripts more readable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I stated already in the comments, PowerShell doesn't require the `Get-` of `Get-*` commands, such as `Get-Vhd`. Instead, you can just type `Vhd`. That being said, you can check for aliases for `Connect-ViServer`.

```
Get-Alias -Definition Connect-ViServer
-----------     ----        
Alias           Get-ESX     
Alias           Get-VC      
Alias           Get-VIServer
```

You see, that in fact there are some aliases to it. One of which is `Get-VC`, thus `vc` is possible.

Comment: Oh, OK, so this does indeed explain it.
I overlooked the fact that Connect-ViServer had Get-* aliases, and thus was also in the scope of your comment.
Even if it works in a totally fishy way, I'll go on using this `vc` shortcut, and now I'll know why it works and where it actually comes from.
Thanks for this clear explanation !

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, this should work.  I don't know why it doesn't show common aliases like "dir" (yes they are defined in the engine https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8970):

```
get-module -ListAvailable | select name,exportedaliases
```

Oh Powershell, you are so varied and mysterious.  ExportedAliases doesn't seem to be much use.

```
gcm get-vc

CommandType     Name       Version    Source
-----------     ----       -------    ------
Alias           Get-VC     11.5.0.... VMware.VimAutomation.Core


get-module VMware.VimAutomation.Core | select name, exportedaliases

Name                      ExportedAliases
----                      ---------------
VMware.VimAutomation.Core {}
```

It seems like the aliases are exported in the module file, *shrug*.  VMware.VimAutomation.Core.psd1, line 46.

```
PS C:\Users\js\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules> ls -r * | select-string get-vc

VMware.VimAutomation.Core\11.5.0.14899560\net45\VMware.VimAutomation.Core.ps1:145:set-alias Get-VC Connect-VIServer
-Scope Global
VMware.VimAutomation.Core\11.5.0.14899560\netcoreapp2.0\VMware.VimAutomation.Core.ps1:145:set-alias Get-VC
Connect-VIServer -Scope Global
VMware.VimAutomation.Core\11.5.0.14899560\VMware.VimAutomation.Core.psd1:46:AliasesToExport = @('Answer-VMQuestion','Ap
ply-DrsRecommendation','Apply-VMHostProfile','Export-VM','Get-ESX','Get-PowerCLIDocumentation','Get-VC','Get-VIServer',
'Get-VIToolkitConfiguration','Get-VIToolkitVersion','Set-VIToolkitConfiguration','Shutdown-VMGuest')
```

I got it this way.

```
Get-Command -Module VMware.VimAutomation.Core -CommandType Alias

CommandType Name                       Version         Source
----------- ----                       -------         ------
Alias       Answer-VMQuestion          11.5.0.14899560 VMware.VimAutomation.Core
Alias       Apply-DrsRecommendation    11.5.0.14899560 VMware.VimAutomation.Core
Alias       Apply-VMHostProfile        11.5.0.14899560 VMware.VimAutomation.Core
Alias       Export-VM                  11.5.0.14899560 VMware.VimAutomation.Core
Alias       Get-ESX                    11.5.0.14899560 VMware.VimAutomation.Core
Alias       Get-PowerCLIDocumentation  11.5.0.14899560 VMware.VimAutomation.Core
Alias       Get-VC                     11.5.0.14899560 VMware.VimAutomation.Core
Alias       Get-VIServer               11.5.0.14899560 VMware.VimAutomation.Core
Alias       Get-VIToolkitConfiguration 11.5.0.14899560 VMware.VimAutomation.Core
Alias       Get-VIToolkitVersion       11.5.0.14899560 VMware.VimAutomation.Core
Alias       Set-VIToolkitConfiguration 11.5.0.14899560 VMware.VimAutomation.Core
Alias       Shutdown-VMGuest           11.5.0.14899560 VMware.VimAutomation.Core
```

Or

```
alias | ? source -match vmware
```

Comment: `vc` does not show up here either, and dir is an alias for Get-Children, which does not come from a module, but from the core language.

Comment: @NicolasMelay I don't have vmware.  Get-childitem comes from the Microsoft.PowerShell.Management module.

Comment: You're right, I ran `Get-Command dir`, saw no source module, and assumed the corresponding cmdlet wasn't pulled from a module, but indeed it is. Maybe this specific alias is defined outside of the module itself.
You can install PowerCLI (VMware's PowerShell modules) from PSGallery if you want to have a look at this `vc` thing : `Install-Module VMware.VimAutomation.Core`.
Sorry this question may have pulled your interest because it started as a generic PowerShell topic, and now looks like being VMware specific. It's still a question about the language and shell's behavior though. ;)